# Time to generate execution plan for select into from a view takes significantly more time than select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, view, select-into

I have a view, vw_example, that is quite complicated and has multiple joins across multiple databases. This view has been causing significant delays when used as part of other queries, and we've narrowed down the problem to execution plan generation.

One thing we've noticed that has vexed us is that this query takes a few seconds to run (and display all the data, ~44k rows):

```
SELECT * FROM vw_example
```

whereas this query takes minutes to run (tbl_example is created by the query):

```
SELECT * INTO tbl_example FROM vw_example
```

We've additionally compared the SQL execution plans between the two in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2014). The former plan took 3 seconds to generate. The latter plan took 37 minutes.

Comparing the two plans, the only difference is that the latter plan has a "Table Insert" node at the start. Everything else is identical.

Does anyone have any idea why it would take significantly longer to generate a plan for the SELECT INTO statement vs a SELECT statement?

Comment: You could have run into this problem: [Generating the SQL query plan takes 5 minutes, the query itself runs in milliseconds. What's up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2615606/880990).

Comment: [long compile times](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/are-long-compile-times-bringing-you-down/) most frequently occur during the search 2 phase of query optimization, where things like join reordering kick into high gear. you can often get a plan much faster by using `OPTION(FORCE ORDER);` when you select from your view, but whether the execution plan is good or not is unpredictable at times.

Comment: I've tried `SELECT * FROM vw_example OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and that makes no difference to the compile time - although I'm not 100% clear that will affect a select statement rather than a stored procedure.

Comment: `OPTION(FORCE ORDER)` got the `SELECT INTO` down to 15s! I'll look into what that changes behind the scenes. Thanks.

Comment: I've seen similar issues with implicit conversions, when the query engine picks the "wrong" column to implicitly convert. I would double-check that the data types are the same on the tables for the joining columns. Remember, character columns are considered a different datatype if they have different lengths.

Comment: Did you try to run `sp_refreshview viewname` and see if you run into the same issue ?

Comment: Note - the version of SSMS is not relevant here. It is the version (and edition) of your database engine that is important. The compatibility mode might also be a factor.

Comment: Try with the query hint (MAXDOP 1)

Comment: >>>Comparing the two plans, the only difference is...<<< Could you please upload both the plans? It can be difference that you just do not see: someone don't se that one plan is serial and other parallel, others don't see that in one plan the clustered index scan is ORDERED and in other is UNORDERED, but these are differences

Comment: Considering 2014 is the first version with the new CE and very long compile time was one thing we saw back then, consider turning on trace flag 4199 and/or lowering the compatibility level for the database to lower than 2014. Doesn't explain the INTO part, but in case it improves things...